# How do I pass post parameters in react native WebView?

Tags: react-native, webview

I have a url I want to open in my app using `WebView` to avoid the user having to be redirected out of the app to the mobile browser. However the the web page I want to show requires some post parameters like from a post form. If it was a GET situation I woul'd have simply appended the parameters to the url.

```
<WebView
    source={{uri: 'https://mypage.com/index.php', headers: '---', body: '---'}}
    style={{marginTop: 20}}
  />
```

Do I put them in `headers` or in `body`, and in what format? Or is there another way? I would like to have the parameters in a key value format i.e `cat=himalayan&dog=pug&fish=shark`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will have to add method in the source prop like this

```
<WebView
    source={{uri: 'https://mypage.com/index.php', headers: '---', body: '---',method:'POST'}}
    style={{marginTop: 20}}
  />
```

Comment: Webview: `source.headers1 is not supported when using POST.

Answer (score 8):

Put this piece of code in the body:

```
{ source: { uri: 'https://mypage.com/index.php', method: 'POST', body: 
'cat=himalayan&dog=pug&fish=shark' }
```

Comment: It worked for me initially but I am not sure what happened its not working now in the backend.

Answer (score 4):

We can do form post in webview in two ways

1st way:

```
const headerObj= { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
const postData = {
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2,
};
let urlEncodedData = '',
  urlEncodedDataPairs = [],
  key;
for (key in postData) {
  urlEncodedDataPairs.push(
    encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(postData[key]),
  );
}
urlEncodedData = urlEncodedDataPairs.join('&').replace(/%20/g, '+');

<WebView
source={{uri: 'https://mypage.com/index.php', headers: headerObj, body: urlEncodedData, method:'POST'}}
style={{marginTop: 20}} />
```

2nd way: Using Html

```
  <WebView
    source={{html: `<html> <body onload="document.forms[0].submit();">
                  <form method="post" action=${this.state.URL}>
                    <input type="hidden" name="key1"  value=${value1} >
                    <input type="hidden" name="key2" value=${tvalue2} >
                  </form >
                </body> </html>`,}}
  />
```

Comment: The headers object is no longer supported when declaring method POST, but that's an easy workaround. Thank You!